# Responsive Website that makes divs fullscreen and user scroll down to see others

Tags: css, responsive

hello i want to make my site responsive.I have divide body in 4 divs. Every 2 divs has the 100% of the screen  and the other two has `margin-top : 50%;`. Now i want everytime `max-width = 800px`, I want every div to has the fullscreen and the user scroll down to see the other divs. My site is https://frontjim.github.io if you want to see it. thanks is advance and sorry for my bad english.
i have used this but it didnt work

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  body,
  html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    min-height: 0;
  }
}

.back {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}


.navbar {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  
}
.mater {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  
}
.cb {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.scroll {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a general container that has child elements. This container has `width: 100vw` and `height: 100vh`, and `display: flex`. You don't need to add `flex-direction: row` since it's the default.

The children will have `width: 100%`.

#### Snippet:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.div1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: blue;
   width: 100%;
}

.div3 {
  background-color: green;
   width: 100%;
}

.div4 {
  background-color: grey;
   width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
</div>

<div class="flex">
  <div class="div3"></div>
  <div class="div4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS Grid, it can get the job done easily

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Responsive Grid</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="div1"></div>
      <div class="div2"></div>
      <div class="div3"></div>
      <div class="div4"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100vh 100vh;
}
.div1 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.div2 {
  background-color: lightseagreen;
}
.div3 {
  background-color: coral;
}
.div4 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .main {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 100vh 100vh 100vh 100vh;
  }
}
```

Live view: https://codepen.io/zgheibali/pen/ZEWWVvr

I hope that my answer was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

change the design.use like this:

in html::

```
<div class='flexyy'>
  <div class='div1'>....</div>
  <div class='div2'>....</div>
  <div class='div3'>....</div>
  <div class='div4'>....</div>
</div>
```

in css::

```
div1{
  width:100%;
}
div2{
  width:100%;
}
div3{
  width:100%;
}
div4{
  width:100%;
}

@media(min-width:800px){
  .div1,.div2,.div3,.div4{
    width:auto;
  }
  .flexyy{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    flex: 0.5 1 auto; 
    flex-wrap:wrap;
  }
}
```